# Swift XMPP messages are lost when client connection lost suddently

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ejabberd, xmmp

I have the same problem discussed in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623833/xmpp-messages-are-lost-when-client-connection-lost-suddently) and surprisingly solution doesn't work for me.

I am using ejabberd server and ios xmppframework. there are two clients, A and B.

> When A and B are online, A can send message to B successfully. If B is
>   offline, B can receive the message when B is online again. But when B
>   is suddenly/unexpectedly lost connection, such as manually close
>   wi-fi, the message sent by A is lost. B will never receive this
>   message. I guess the reason is that B lost connection suddenly and the
>   server still think B is online. Thus the offline message does work
>   under this condition.

So my question is how to ensure the message that sent by A will be received by B? To ensure there is no messages lost.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the question you are referring to - you need to use **Stream Management (XEP-0198)**. It provides a solution for the cases like your - when Internet Connection is bad and you can lost time to time your connection. There is no other solution for your issue -  XEP-0198 is exactly what you need

Comment: I have already implemented Stream Management in my project but still I am facing message skipping issue.

Comment: I think you missed something because SM gives you a 100% durability